# how I validating this

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Private Sub Command261_Click()

 If IsNull(CompanyName.Value Or ID.Value Or Date_Received.Value Or Clerk_Revceived) = "" Then
   
 MsgBox "Please Complete Company Name"
  
   cancel = False
 
 Else
    DoCmd.Close
     
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that "how I validating this" is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Command261_Click()

    If IsNull(CompanyName.Value + ID.Value + Date_Received.Value + Clerk_Revceived.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Please Complete Company Info"  
        ' Cancel = True       ' Nothing to cancel here.
    Else
        DoCmd.Close     
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If IsNull(CompanyName.Value + ID.Value + Date_Received.Value + Clerk_Revceived.Value) Then it works cause yes it give me the message to complete but still it gave me the type mismatch error. Thank you Gustav